# How to use valves in Jboss EAP 7?

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

I migrate JBoss EPA 6 to JBoss EAP 7, now valves are doesn't work. I want to know how to use valves in JBoss EAP 7.

Answer (score 0):

Valves are replaced by filters in Undertow.
Predefined  (aka the ones that were shipped) valves can be migrated with the /subsystem=web:migrate operation. For custom ones you need to create new filters.
Look into the windup project as it helps a lot with version migration.

Comment: As per the documentation, the valve are replaced by handlers (JBOSS v7.3)

Comment: "Custom valves and valves that are defined in the jboss-web.xml file must be rewritten or replaced by the corresponding Undertow built-in handler. For information about mapping valves to Undertow handlers, see Migrate JBoss Web Valves. Authentication valves must be replaced manually using Undertow built-in authentication mechanisms
"